# Create new jquery ui tab panel with close button inside the panel?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I've got a function worked out that creates a new query ui tab panel when a user clicks a button. It also creates a new tab with a close button in it, like so:

```
$(function newTab() {
var $tabs = $('#nav-tabs').tabs();
$('.add-tab').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var tabName = $(this).text(),
        tabLink = $(this).attr('href'),
        tabNumber = -1;
    $tabs.find('.nav-tab-menu li a').each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).text() == tabName) {
            tabNumber = i;
        }
    });
    if (tabNumber >= 0) {
        $tabs.tabs('option', 'active', tabNumber)
    } else {
        $("<li><a href=" + tabLink + " class='ui-icon-tab-add'>" + tabName + "</a><span class='ui-icon-close' role='presentation'><span class='sr'>Remove Tab</span></span></li>")
            .appendTo(".nav-tab-menu");
        $("#nav-tabs").tabs("refresh");
        $('#nav-tabs').tabs('option', 'active', -1);
    }   
    return false
    })
});
```

It works great, but this client is a total pain in the ass, and one close button isn't good enough for them - they also want one in the newly created panel as well. I've tried cloning the button and appending it to the panel, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? I should mention that the content of the current tab is replaced when the user clicks a link, so the button probably needs to be inserted before the active tab panel, rather than inside it so it doesn't get removed when the content is updated.

Comment: What does your starting HTML look like? Maybe put it all in a fiddle.

Comment: There's a ton of included files and ajax includes, so it won't work well in a fiddle. But here's a link: http://bit.ly/1vXUM6i